# How do I access useAccordion methods and properties? (ChakraUI React Hook)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, chakra-ui

I have a ChakraUI accordion that I need to manually change the open index based on section name/id, since elements are hidden/shown depending on view/edit state, and this is causing the open index to open the wrong panel when switching state.

I see the useAccordion hook in their code, but I don't understand why it takes accordion props, which I declare in  (allowToggle, allowMultiple, etc).

Wouldn't the hook want a ref or ID? I'm confused on how this hook and the JSK element connect.

useAccordion looks like this:

```
declare function useAccordion(props: UseAccordionProps): {
  index: ExpandedIndex;
  setIndex: react.Dispatch<react.SetStateAction<ExpandedIndex>>;
  htmlProps: {};
  getAccordionItemProps: (idx: number | null) => {
    isOpen: boolean;
    onChange: (isOpen: boolean) => void;
  };
  focusedIndex: number;
  setFocusedIndex: react.Dispatch<react.SetStateAction<number>>;
  descendants: _chakra_ui_descendant.DescendantsManager<HTMLButtonElement, {}>;
};
```

I was thinking it should look like:

```
const {index, setIndex, htmlProps} = useAccordion(ref)
```

But that goes against their type defs. Maybe I'm missing something about hooks? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know that it goes against their type defs?

Comment: declare function useAccordion(props: UseAccordionProps) -- UseAccordionProps is an interface with all the html attributes on <Accordion allowToggle defaultIndex={0} etc./>

Comment: [UseAccordionProps](https://github.com/chakra-ui/chakra-ui/blob/3e1b3f6b6a7398b71ac08339110f075695fbae94/packages/components/accordion/src/use-accordion.ts#L18)

Comment: I see that. Im wondering why there isn't a ref attribute or something so I can point the hook to the right element.